# tooltip div with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## objective

I have a div that I want to make act like a tooltip with reactjs.

### HTML

```
<div>on hover here we will show the tooltip</div>
<div>
    <div class="tooltip_custom">this is the tooltip!!</div>
</div>
```

I am used to angularjs using the `ng-show` with a condition on the `<div>` , I was wondering if there is such binding in reactjs , or else how can I do this functionality ?

Thanks

Answer (score 29):

You can make your component to return the following markup

```
return (
  <div>
    <div onMouseOver={this.handleMouseIn.bind(this)} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut.bind(this)}>on hover here we will show the tooltip</div>
    <div>
      <div style={tooltipStyle}>this is the tooltip!!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Where `tooltipStyle` is assigned like this:

```
const tooltipStyle = {
  display: this.state.hover ? 'block' : 'none'
}
```

So tooltip depends on component state, now in `handleMouseIn` and `handleMouseOut` you need to change component state to make tooltip visible.

```
handleMouseIn() {
  this.setState({ hover: true })
}

handleMouseOut() {
  this.setState({ hover: false })
}
```

Here is working [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwWRVb).

You can start diving in React with this article: [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Comment: thanks , how about if I want the external div to have its own content rendered outside in html ,, and all I want to add is add the behaviour of hover to it ,, so say this hover functionality can be a reusable module for tooltips ?

Comment: I mean I dont want to build the onMouseOver div inside my reactjs code ,, I just want to add the hover behaviour on it , doable ?

Comment: @sisimh you could use composition, something like a wrapper that will help you to achieve this without repeating yourself in multiple places. Though it depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Working example doesn't work anymore. You need to import React from Codepen instead of the custom URL.

Answer (score 21):

I think whatever you want to show as tooltip, just add that to the "title" of the div where you want to show it.

Eg:

```
<div title="I am the tooltip text">I am the div where you should hover</div>
```

But if its a custom designed div then go as the answers given before.

Comment: simple and pragmatic, thanks

Comment: Exactly, simple and pragmatic.  The only downside I see is that you have to wait that default amount of time before the popup actually shows (maybe a browser setting?) versus using other custom library or package which I've used before that display the popup immediately on hover.  But thanks as mentioned, this works for most situations.

Answer (score 14):

One option is just to do it in CSS. It's not quite as flexible, but with markup like:

```
<div className="tooltip-on-hover">Hover here</div>
<div className="tooltip">This is the tooltip</div>
```

You could do:

```
.tooltip {
  ...
  visibility: hidden;  /* Or display: none, depending on how you want it to behave */
}

.tooltip-on-hover:hover + .tooltip {    /* Uses the adjacent sibling selector */
  visibility: visible;  /* Or display: block */
}
```

Example:

```css
.tooltip { display: none; }
.tooltip-on-hover:hover + .tooltip { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-on-hover">Hover here</div>
<div class="tooltip">This is the tooltip</div>
```

You could also nest the tooltip inside the element so you could use a normal descendant selector like `.tooltip-on-hover:hover .tooltip`. You could even use a `::before` or `::after` pseudo-element, there are guides around on how to do this.

Comment: You should be using `className` rather than `class` for React.

Comment: @kojow7 That's true if we're talking about JSX, good catch. I just referred to it as markup though, which technically could just be the HTML output (especially since nothing in my answer is React specific), and it mimics the "HTML" that was written in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Install npm package:

```
npm install react-tooltip
```

Usage:

```
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";

<div data-tip="msg to show" data-for='toolTip1' data-place='top'>Tooltip</div>
<ReactTooltip id="toolTip1" />
```

Comment: I tryied and works like a charm. Thanks for this example!!!

Comment: Still works in 2021. Thank you boss. Been wondering why my conditional render and various other try outs didn't work. Please explain the rationale behind using *data-* attributes and why isn't this in their docs for React ToolTip? Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `React Mapple ToolTip` which is easy to use and customize and also comes with predefined themes.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of this library

[image]
[reactjs-mappletooltip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-mappletooltip)

Comment: Missing a disclosure there, since its your library. Handy, but messes a bit with the fine alignment of the divs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use react-tooltip package. Super easy to use and handy also.

Installation: npm i react-tootip.

Example:
1. import it :

```
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip"
```

2. Include it in your component:

   `<div className="createContent">
         **<ReactTooltip />**
         <div className="contentPlaceholder">`
3. add tool tip to your button/div or any element: **data-tip="add tooltip message"**

`<button className="addSection" data-tip="add tooltip message" onClick={() => this.onAddChild()}>+</button>`

package url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

Answer (score 1):

```
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
```

```
const HtmlTooltip = withStyles((theme) => ({
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,250,228)',
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)',
      maxWidth: 400,
      fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(12),
      border: '1px solid #dadde9',
    },
  }))(Tooltip);
```

```
 headerName: 'FEEDBACK',
    field: "remarks",
      flex: 0.30,
        renderCell: (params: GridCellParams) => (
          <Grid>
            <HtmlTooltip title={params.value} placement="bottom">
              <Typography style={{ color: "inherit", cursor: "pointer" }}>{params.value}</Typography>
            </HtmlTooltip>
          </Grid>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you are using react-bootstrap in your project, then use https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/ Overlay with the tooltip.

MouseEnter and MoverLeave need to be used though.

```
<OverlayTrigger
  placement="right"
  delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
  overlay={renderTooltip}>
   <div>on hover here we will show the tooltip</div>
</OverlayTrigger>
```