# ReactJS with material-ui is it possible to have the tooltip behaviour on hover of a div?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was wondering if the tooltip like this:
[tooltip from material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button)

that occurs on icon can be possible onHover of a div?
Or do I have to create it by hand?

I tried this:
[tooltip div with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423644/tooltip-div-with-reactjs)

but none of the 2 solutions is currently working.

Comment: Though very pretty, I've found material-ui to be limiting in a lot of ways. For arbitrary tooltips, check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip.

Comment: Interesting, I just discovered the same library :) And I agree with you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> can be possible onHover of a div? Or do I have to create it by hand?

You have to create it of course. It is unclear what you mean by `onHover`, if you want you can use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to create relatively positioned tooltip.

Alternatively it is super simple to use a simple CSS tooltip : http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/ driven by `data-` attributes (supported natively by react).

Comment: You perfectly answer my question :) I used the library that we were discussing with lux in commentary, but I might migrate for the solution described in your link. 
Thank you very much man

Comment: Outstanding source for lightweight tooltips! I'd like this more than once if I could