# data-tooltip returns [Object object]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, jsx

When displaying text in data-tooltip, the inscription [Object object] is displayed

```js
import React from "react";
import { FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

const translate = (id, value={}) => <FormattedMessage id={id} values={{...value}} />

export default translate;
```

```js
<span>
  {translate("resizeImage")}
    <span
      class="material-icons tooltipped"
      data-tooltip={translate("ResizeImageInfo")}
    >
    info
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: `[Object object]` means you're converting an object directly to a string.

Comment: Try using JSON.Parse();

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `translate("ResizeImageInfo")` function return an object instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

`data-tooltip` attribute only works with string.
https://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/how-to-insert-tooltips.shtml

but your translate function returns React component. As a result it only shows [Object, object].

To implement tooltip feature in react please consider using this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip
Or please consider implement this.
[tooltip div with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423644/tooltip-div-with-reactjs)